# Moving SpriteNodes outwards in a circular pattern

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a function that creates 8 bullets coming from the player in a circle firing outwards. I think the problem lies with this line here:

```
let endPoint = CGPoint(x: distance * cos(angle), y:  distance * sin(angle))
```

This causes the bullets to move faster in the bottom left of the circle than the ones in the top right, when in fact they should all move the same distance at the same speed.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

```
func fireSpecialWeapon() {

    stride(from: 0, to: 2 * CGFloat.pi, by: 2 * CGFloat.pi / 8 ).forEach { angle in
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bulletCircle")
        bullet.setScale(3)
        bullet.zRotation = angle
        bullet.position = player.position
        bullet.zPosition = 2

        //move outwards to the edge of the screen
        let distance: CGFloat = 1000
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: distance * cos(angle), y:  distance * sin(angle))
        let move = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 2)

        self.addChild(bullet)
        bullet.run(move)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a different question to the one I commented on?

Comment: SKAction move makes them fly in a straight line, and no, the bullets are not moving faster, they are moving the distance you specify (1000 points) in 2 seconds

Comment: if the bullets are moving faster from the bottom left then the top right, that means your anchor points are (0,0) not (0.5,0.5)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks! the anchor points was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the bullets are moving faster from the bottom left then the top right, that means your anchor points are (0,0) not (0.5,0.5)